# PyGObject Install Child Properties by Creating ParamSpec

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to convert a pygtk library called etk.docking to pygobject. As part of this I have a `Gtk.Container` class that has child properties defined in a `__gchild_properties__` dictionary. These object properties that are not specific to either the container or the contained widget, but to the relationship. The library also uses it to connect to the child-widget notification for updates to the property value.

```
__gchild_properties__ = {
    'weight': (GObject.TYPE_FLOAT,
               'item weight',
               'item weight',
               0,  # min
               1,  # max
               .2,  # default
               GObject.ParamFlags.READWRITE
               ),
}
```

I am then trying to install the child properties using this for-loop on the above dictionary (`DockPaned` is the `Container`):

```
for index, (name, pspec) in enumerate(six.iteritems(DockPaned.__gchild_properties__)):
    pspec = list(pspec)
    pspec.insert(0, name)
    Gtk.ContainerClass.install_child_property(DockPaned, index + 1, tuple(pspec))
```

From the last line I get a

> TypeError: argument pspec: Expected GObject.ParamSpec, but got tuple

I understand that built in GObject class properties use the GObject. `ParamSpec` as an object structure to hold the properties. What I don't see is a way in PyGObject to create my own `ParamSpec`.

For normal Properties, the PyGObject User Guide uses [GObject.Property](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/properties.html#GObject.Property) as a decorator to create new properties. The [Python GTK+3 Tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/objects.html#GObject.GObject.__gproperties__) also shows the use of `GObject.Property` as a constructor to create the property, also shows its use as a decorator, and a verbose dictionary form. However, there is no mention of child properties.

Things I have tried:

1. Searching for the API (pgi-docs) for a `GObject.ParamSpec` constructor, I don't see how to create one unless I created it in C first as a struct and then passed it back to pygobject somehow.
2. Defining this weight property directly to the child object. This doesn't work since then I get errors that the child property doesn't exist since a child property is not the same as a property applied to a child object.
3. Searching the API for any alternatives to `install_child_property` that doesn't require a `ParamSpec`, so that I could use the tuple I have defined.

Comment: Today I also tried adding the weight property as a property of DockPaned, and then replaced the for loop with:

Comment: `Gtk.ContainerClass.install_child_property(DockPaned, 2, GObject.list_properties(DockPaned))`


Unfortunately, I am getting the same error.

Comment: I also determined that the GObject.param_spec_float method can create a pspec. Unfortunately now I am still getting a different type error: Expected GObject.ParamSpec, but got gobject.GParamSpec. I have submitted a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784991) the the GNOME Bugzilla